# python should class variables be initialised to a dummy value when real value is yet to be assigned?

Tags: python, class, oop, class-variables

I have a class in python with a mainly static method. These static methods assign some values to the class variables like so:

```
class A:

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        A.first = 20

    @staticmethod
    def foo2():
        return A.first **2
```

`foo2` will always run after `foo` in my case. My question is should I initialise `first` to some dummy value in the class scope such as:

```
class A:
    A.first = None

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        A.first = 20

    @staticmethod
    def foo2():
        return A.first **2
```

**NOTE:** The IDE gives a warning of `unresolved attribute reference 'first' for class A` when `first` is accessed in `foo2`. This warning is reasonable which is why I was thinking to initialise `first` to a dummy placeholder.

what's the best practice here?

Comment: "I have a class in python with a mainly static method. These static methods assign some values to the class variables like so:" That just doesn't make any sense. Why not use instance variables? Also, you should probably use `classmethod`s instead of staticmethods if you are going to modify the class state. But fundamentally, "a class in python with a mainly static method" is major code smell.

Comment: I agree to initialise it first (as in your second code). You probably shouldn't trust in `foo2` that `foo` was called and insert an `assert A.first is not None`. Disclamer: I also assume that what you show is a quite reduced example, because as the comment above states, this example as such is bad design.

Comment: Then what is the point of static methods? I know for a fact that I am not going to have multiple instances of this class. So why not make static methods? (in fact there are such things like static classes in other programming languages)

Comment: Concerning `@static` vs `@class` method and *code smell* or not: If you have a class with only `@staticmethod`s `@classmethod`s and class vars, then this is one way of creating a name space.

You could achieve kind of the same thing with a separate module.

I can't really say, whether this is bad or good practice. and whether you're better off with a separate module.

I think it's a possible way of coding, though I use mostly modules

Comment: @user7331538 staticmethods mainly exist to appease people coming from languages like Java, where everything is a class definition. The fundamental unit of code organization in Python is a *module*, not a class. If you were going to create a static class in another language, then in Python, **that should just be a module with regular functions in it**. If you have mutable global state in that module, then you should have been using an instance to *begin with*.

Answer (score 2):

I personally think it's very good to write code, that is flagged clean by tools like `flake`, `flake8`, `prospector`, `pylint` or whatever your IDE is using.

In some cases this means writing lines, that are not strictly necessary or rewriting your code in a slighly different manner just to *please* a tool. 
I think mostly it's worth it.

In most cases it helps avoiding difficult to read code or strange mistakes.
This implies, that even if not strictly necessary it's better to explicitly declare a class variable with a dummy value even if the real value will be set later.

People reading your code will easier see, that you have class variables.

Another comment:

Though

```
class A:
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        A.first = 20
```

works, it is a little weird.

`@staticmethod` is intended for functions, that require neither any class attribute nor a class instance, but you have then an *explicit* reference to `A`

What is more common is to write:

```
class A:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def foo(cls):
        cls.first = 20
```

`@classmethod` indicates, that you want to access class members or other class methods, but that you don't need an instance. So exactly what you try to achieve.

Which has also the advantage, that there will be less issues if you ever create a class that inherits from `A` (and if you ever rename the class there are less lines to change)

Comment: Yes you are right. However  I didn't want to repeat the already discussed code. 
As you see I didn't add the declaration of `foo2` either.
I'll make a tiny change  (adding `...`) to make it clear this is just partial code.
If you think this is not clear I can do as you suggested and add `first = None`

Tell me what you think

Alternatively I could just remove the head line `class A:`

Comment: I would like to improve my answer so that is easy to read, complete and not ambiguous. The answer got down voted. It would be great to tell me what I could improve. I am very motivated to improve my answers, so that they are useful to SO. Just down voting doesn't help a lot.

I got one feedback (which got deleted meanwhile) suggesting to add `first = None` to my two examples. I replied and asked whether my suggested fix is OK or whether adding `first = None`  would be better.
Never got an answer, just saw that an up vote got transformed into a down vote.